# Is the Alexandroff extension of a locally compact, second-countable space second-countable?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactification, second-countable, alexandroff-compactification

If $X$ is a locally compact, second-countable topological space, then is its Alexandroff extension $X^*$ also second-countable?

Our definition of locally compact is that for every $x$ in $X$, we have an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $\operatorname{cl}_X U$ is compact and $x \in U$. I was able to prove that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $X$, then the subset

$$
\bigl\{U \in \mathcal{B} : \text{$\operatorname{cl}_X U$ is compact}\bigr\}
$$

is also a base for $X$. So we can assume without loss of generality that our (countably many) basic open sets have compact closure.

Since the set of finite subsets of a countable set is also countable, we have that the set $\mathcal{B}_\mathrm{f}$ of finite unions of sets in $\mathcal{B}$ is also countable. Define

$$
\mathcal{C} := \mathcal{B} \cup \bigl\{X^* \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X U : U \in \mathcal{B}_\mathrm{f}\bigr\}
$$

which is a countable collection of open subsets of $X^*$.

Is the following proof that every open subset of $X^*$ is a union of sets in $\mathcal{C}$ correct?

Let $x \in U$ which is an open subset of $X^*$. If $x$ is a point in $X$, then $U \cap X$ is open in $X$, and so there is a $V$ in $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \subset U \cap X \subset U$. Otherwise $x$ is the point at infinity, so $U = X^* \setminus K$ where $K$ is a compact, closed subset of $X$. We can cover $K$ by finitely many sets $U_n$ in $\mathcal{B}$, so that $K \subset \bigcup_n U_n \in \mathcal{B}_\mathrm{f}$. It follows that $x \in X^*\setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \bigl(\bigcup_n U_n\bigr)$ which is contained in $X^* \setminus K = U$.

In both cases, we have found a set in $\mathcal{C}$ which is a neighborhood of the point $x$ and is contained in $U$. Hence, $\mathcal{C}$ is a base for $X^*$.

Comment: Are you sure "It follows that $x \in X^*\setminus \operatorname{cl}_X \bigl(\bigcup_n U_n\bigr)$"? I can only see that $x \in X^*\setminus \bigl(\bigcup_n U_n\bigr).$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One point compactification is second countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579080/one-point-compactification-is-second-countable)

Comment: @AnneBauval I suppose that since $K \subset \bigcup_n U_n \subset \operatorname{cl}_X\bigl(\bigcup_n U_n\bigr)$, then the reverse inequality holds for their complements in $X^*$. As for the possible duplicate, I think these are different questions since I don't assume the space is Hausdorff.

Comment: And actually the closure in $X$ is a subset of $X$, and therefore doesn't contain the point at infinity (which I was assuming $x$ was in that context).

Comment: The definition of "locally compact" is unusual. I would expect taht each point $x$ has  a compact neigbhborhood, but not necessarily a closed compact one.

Comment: I agree that "the reverse inequality holds for their complements" but this didn't prove the claim, knowing only that $x$ belongs to $X^*\setminus K.$ On the other hand, for $x=\infty$, the same claim is obvious hence why such an intricate argument?

Comment: @PaulFrost I think you make a good point. I have seen the property I used be referred to as *strongly* locally compact before.

Comment: @AnneBauval I needed to find a set in $\mathcal{C}$ which is contained in $X^* \setminus K$ and is a neighborhood of $x$ (which in the context of my proof there was the point at infinity). We both agree that $X^* \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X\bigl(\bigcup_n U_n\bigr)$ achieves the first part by reversing the inequality, and it achieves the second part of being a neighborhood of $x = \infty$ which we both also agree on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of "locally compact" is unusual. I know two variants:

1. Each point has a compact neighborhood.
2. Each point has a neighborhood base consisting of compact sets.

They are equivalent for Hausdorff spaces, but you do not require spaces to be Hausdorff. As you say, you use

3. Each point has a compact *closed* neighborhood.

This property also seems to be denoted as *strongly locally compact*.

In the context of the Alexandroff extension this variant is in fact extremely useful because the open neigborhoods of $\infty$ in $X^*$ are precisely the complements $X^* \setminus K$, where $K \subset X$ is compact and closed in $X$.

Your proof is correct. Its essence is that $X$ has a countable base $\mathcal B$ with the following properties:

- For each $U \in \mathcal B$ the closure $\operatorname{cl}_X U$ is compact.
- Each compact $K \subset X$ is contained is some $U \in \mathcal B$.

You start with a countable base $\mathcal B_0$ of $X$ and observe that $\mathcal B_1 = \{ U \in \mathcal B \mid \operatorname{cl}_X U \in \mathcal B \}$ is also a base for $X$ (which is clearly countable). Then trivially the set $\mathcal B$ of all finite unions of elements of $\mathcal B_1$ is again a basis. Clearly $\mathcal B$ is countable and for each $U \in \mathcal B$ the closure $\operatorname{cl}_X U$ is compact. This holds because if $U = \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ with $U_i \in \mathcal B_1$, then $U \subset C := \bigcup_{i=1}^n \operatorname{cl}_X U_i$, thus $\operatorname{cl}_X U \subset C$. Because $C$ is compact and $\operatorname{cl}_X U$ is closed in $C$, it is compact. Moreover each compact $K \subset X$ can be covered by finitely many $U_i \in \mathcal B_0$, thus it is contained in some $U \in \mathcal B$.

Therefore $\mathcal{C} := \mathcal{B} \cup \bigl\{X^* \setminus \operatorname{cl}_X U : U \in \mathcal{B}\bigr\}
$ is a countable base of $X^*$.

Comment: You consolidated the properties of a desirable countable base pretty well with those two bullet points. I'll admit while coming up with my solution I was adding more sets to my base *ad hoc* at times when I realized I didn't have enough basic sets to prove the next fact. So I appreciate that you stripped the construction to its essentials with those two properties. Working backwards from that is cleaner, but of course, I didn't have that foresight when I was sketching up the proof 